# FastAPI with multiple and filtered foreign keys

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

In a model I have two foreign keys pointing to two different tables where the second one depends on the first one. 
For example:

```
class Bank(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Banks'
    BankId: Column(SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Agency(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Agencies'
    AgencyId: Column(SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    ...

class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Customers'
    Id: Column(SmallInteger, primary_key=True)
    BankId: Column(SmallInteger, ForeignKey("Banks.IdBank", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)
    AgencyId: Column(SmallInteger, ForeignKey("Agencies.IdAgency", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=True)

    Bank = relationship("Banks", uselist=False)
    Agency = relationship("Agencies", uselist=False)
```

What I want is to have the current agency filtered for the bank Id. 
Actually the foreign keys work but there is no filtering between them. 
I mean, if I have BankId with value 20 and AgencyId with value 10, it doesn't take me the agency with value 10 for the bank with value 20 but it takes me the first match in the table (Agencies), regardless of the bank. 
This is my JSON result:

```
{
    ...
    "Bank": {
        "BankId": 20,
        ...
    },
    "Agency": {
        "BankId": 1,
        "AgencyId": 10,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

What can I do in order to get the correct information? 
Thank you all.

**FIRST EDIT** 
This is my "controller" code.

```
def get_customer(CustomerId: str, db: Session=Depends(get_db)):
    customer = db.query(customer_model.Customer).filter(customer_model.Customer.Id == CustomerId).first()  
    if customer is None:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=404,
            detail='Customer not found'
        )
    else:
        return customer
```

Comment: How are you querying your table? `.filter(Customer.BankId == 20, Customer.AgencyId == 10)` should give you only those entries that have both ids set to the expected values.

Comment: I have modified the request adding my controller code.

Comment: There is nothing in that query that is filtering based on BankId or AgencyId - why do you expect that to be taken into account?